# 重複しないUUIDをデータベースに保存するには？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

`Ruby on Rails`などのWebサービスでそれぞれのユーザーに重複しないUUIDを付与したいです。

`SHA256`や`Base64`などでハッシュ値をUUIDとすればいいでしょうか？

ですが、ここで問題となるのが、ハッシュ値は衝突する可能性がゼロではないという事実です。

そのため、UUID を生成するたびにデータベースに重複するUUID が存在しないか確かめる判断をコードとして書くことが必要になります。ですが、極めて重複が起こりにくいのに毎回重複を調べるのは手間だと思うんです、

この手間を省きたい。

そのため、UUID として完全に重複しない値が得る方法が知りたいのですが、どのような関数が推奨されるのでしょうか？

Comment: "UUID 重複" 等でweb検索すると、衝突の可能性に対しての考え方が色々出てきますので、まずはそれらを参照してみるとよいかもしれません。

Comment: こんな記事があるようですが。[railsでモデルにuuidを持たせる実装について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/37075/26370)